# Could not find installable ISAM

Tags: forms, ms-access, asp-classic, database-connection, isam

I want to create a search function in my webpage with first

```
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="get" action="mySearchResults.asp">
  <label>Enter Keywords:`
  <input type="text" name="searchTerm" />`
  </label>`
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" />
  </p>
</form>
```

Then

```
<% 
'open the connection
Dim Connect, myRecordSet
Set Connect = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Connect.Open = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Database='SVCS.mdb'"
%>

<%
'collect the form input
searchInput = Request.QueryString("searchTerm")`

'check for a match
Set myRecordSet = Connect.Execute ("SELECT * FROM Inventory WHERE myColumn LIKE '%" & searchInput & "%'")


'display the results
if myRecordSet.EOF then
response.write("You searched for: " & searchInput & "<br>")
response.write("A match was not found.<br>Sorry try again.")
else
response.write("You searched for: " & searchInput & "<br>")
response.write("The record was found!<br>The match is: " & myRecordSet("myColumn"))
end if
%>
<br><br>
<a href="mySearchForm.asp">Try Again</a>
```

And the error is

```
Microsoft JET Database Engine error '80004005' 
Could not find installable ISAM. 
/sarah lee video club website/mySearchResults.asp, line 5
```

Please tell me how to solve this

Comment: You can use the code button `{}` to format your code.

Answer (score 0):

You should not quote the database name for one thing, it is Data Source, not Database, and you do not need the equals with Open.

```
Set con = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection") 
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=SVCS.mdb"
```

See also http://connectionstrings.com